# how to get the text in the html in python

Tags: python

I wanted to capture some of the text in html using python. 
example..

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib

open = urllib.urlopen('http://localhost/main.php')
read = open.read()
print read
```

and this source code of the target url

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
This is body!
</body>
</html>
```

and how if I just want to catch the words "This is body!" only!?
Please guys, help me with this matter!

---

For example, HTML is replaced by this one:

```
<table width=90% align=center>
  <tr>
    <td>The information available on this site freely accessible to the public</td>
  <tr>
</table>
<table class=adminlist border=0 width=90% cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 align=center>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=5 colspan=2><img src=images/Forum.png><br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i><b>Phone</b></td><td>: +61 2 4446 5552</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i><b>Name</b></td><td>: Stundet</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i><b>Class</b></td>
    <td>: Summer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><i><b>Email</b></td>
    <td>: student@localhost.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and i want to make this output:

```
Phone : +61 2 4446 5552
Name  : Student
Class : Summer
Email : student@localhost.com
```

only caught the words the core of the html.. :)

Answer (score 6):

Try [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

...

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.findAll("body").string
```

Comment: i found these errors like this 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Answer (score 4):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
This is body!
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.find('body').string
```

Comment: i found these errors like this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Comment: i'm sorry sir, your code is working. but what if I want to find a text that doesn't exist in the tag. :)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give an example?

Comment: like this, how to capture text html, for example from <title> until </html>

Comment: Grab the text from title first, then concatenate it with the text from body? `soup.find('title').string + soup.find('body').string`?